# How to truncate text without affect filtering

Tags: angularjs

In this fiddle the table can be filtered :

http://jsfiddle.net/eBcaB/232/

I have added a truncate function which will truncate text :

```
   $scope.truncate = function(item){
    return item.substring(0,2);
   }
```

But I'm unsure how to integrate this function to truncate items and not affect the filtering of results. How to truncate text and also maintain filtering functionality, so the any text that is removed as part of truncation can still be filtered ?

fiddle src :

```
<div ng-app>

        <div ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">        

            <br />
            <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Any: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.$" /></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
            <br />
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:mySortFunction | filter:search">
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
</div>
</div>
.bold { font-weight:bold; }

table td{
    padding: 10px;
}

table th{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

function ShoppingCartCtrl($scope)  {

        $scope.items = [
            {Name: "Soap", Price: "25", Quantity: "10"},
            {Name: "Shaving cream", Price: "50", Quantity: "15"},
            {Name: "Shampoo", Price: "100", Quantity: "5"}
        ];

   $scope.truncate = function(item){
    return item.substring(0,2);
   }

}
```

Comment: What you want to truncate? Anyway seem you just want to make your own truncate filter to ahve in html: {{smth | truncate:2 }}

Comment: @Petr Averyonav want to filter the name field. So just first 3 characters a displayed to user but if match occurs on text that is truncated the name field text is still displayed

Comment: ouch, you really work with angular 1.0.3?

Comment: `<td>{{ truncate(item.Name) }}</td>`

Comment: @Petr Averyonav can use later version of angular

Comment: u can launch function as suggested above or u can use custom filter: http://jsfiddle.net/7og42xxf/